# Getting correct sampling frequency, how to?

Tags: fft, frequency, nyquist

I am trying to fully understand the sampling frequency concept. I got a useful answer from PaxRomana99 ([I need help setting up the correct frequency vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227950/i-need-help-setting-up-the-correct-frequency-vector)) and it seems like the way to get the correct frequency vector is when you set up the time interval to be related to fs:

t = 0:1/fs:10; % 10 seconds of data sampled at fs
y = sin(2*pi*100.*t); 
However, in my case, I have no control on how my time interval is set up, I am given 2 arrays, one is the time interval and one is the sinusoidal wave resulting from that time interval. So should I got through the time array and extract fs? which should be the spacing between the time steps? am I in the wrong path here?
Thanks for any hints and any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you suggest, you get the sampling frequency from the time array.  It's just 1/(time sample interval).